# I will break your vase

Tags: grammar

> 1. I ***will*** break your vase.
> 2. I will break your vase!
> 3. I'll break your vase.
> 4. I will break your vase.

---

Which one is stronger in meaning between Sentence 1 and Sentence 2? Is it #2?
Between #1 and #4, #1 is stronger than #4, isn't it? In #1, the subject has a strong volition than #4. Is 'will' #4 just a simple future? Or does 'will' in #4 have a volition weaker than as in #1? What about # 3? A contracted form is used here. In #, does the subject have a volition weaker than #1?

Comment: Stronger still is "I breaka you face."

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 because of the exclamation mark (!). It emphasizes the tone of the sentence used.